# How do I compare strings correctly with only part of the options within?

Tags: python, compare

I am working on a project in which have to search a string of text for various sub-strings and I have found myself hitting a problem of that when the string being searched possesses all the possible 'sub-strings' then it functions well and I can assess the data, however when it has only part of the sub-strings within i.e. 3 out of 6 options, then it doesn't work.

Below is the code in C.

```
    with open(argv[1], "r") as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            valid = False
            for row in reader:
                if str_count['AGATC'] == int(row['AGATC']) and str_count['TTTTTTCT'] == int(row['TTTTTTCT']) and str_count['AATG'] == int(row['AATG']) and str_count['TCTAG'] == int(row['TCTAG']) and str_count['GATA'] == int(row['GATA']) and str_count['TATC'] == int(row['TATC']) and str_count['GAAA'] == int(row['GAAA']) and str_count['TCTG'] == int(row['TCTG']):
                    print(row['name'])
                    valid = True
            if valid == False:
                print("No match")
```

The question is how can I get it to function if I am dealing with a string with only part of the options. For example if I have a string like:

> name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG

It works well, however if I have the following:

> TTTTTTCT,AGATC,AATG,TATC

I would like to avoid hard-coding and I would appreciate any assistance possible.

Comment: What's the expected behavior for the edge case you're presenting, would one with three fields but matching one be printed and `valid = True` ?

Comment: no so the expected behaviour is if the AGATC and AATG and TATC all match then valid would = True. as is the case as its meant to search a sequence of letters representing DNA and counting accordingly and if they all match then theoretically you have your person, now all other parts function as needed, except here I am not sure how to allow it to only use the fields provided by the csv file for the calculations that way if the csv only has 3 or 5 fields it still works

Comment: basically all the fields present in the csv file except name need to match to that which is determined in the program in order to trace the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Python [all](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp) Function

**Replace**

```
if str_count['AGATC'] == int(row['AGATC']) and str_count['TTTTTTCT'] == int(row['TTTTTTCT']) and str_count['AATG'] == int(row['AATG']) and str_count['TCTAG'] == int(row['TCTAG']) and str_count['GATA'] == int(row['GATA']) and str_count['TATC'] == int(row['TATC']) and str_count['GAAA'] == int(row['GAAA']) and str_count['TCTG'] == int(row['TCTG']):
```

**With**

```
all(str_count[k]==int(v) for k, v in row.items() if k != 'name'):
```

**Explanation**

row is a dictionary of k, v pairs based upon the header (first) row.

For instance if the header row is: name,AGATC,AATG,TATC, each row will be:

```
{'name':v1,
  'AGATC':v2,
  'AATG: v3,
  'TATC': v4}
```

Where v1, v2, v3, v4 varies by row but keys are always the same.

Expression:

```
row.items()
```

Is a list of key, value pairs (tuples) for a dictionary, as in:

```
[('name', v1), ('AGATC':v2), ('AATG: v3), ('TATC': v4)]
```

Want to loop over these tuples to seek if str_count(k) == int(vi), except for k == 'name'.

Use list comprehension to get all the tuples except for where k == 'name'

```
[(k, v) for k, v in row.items() if k != 'name']
```

Want to check that all the k, v pairs in this list satisfy a condition

```
all([str_count(k)==int(v) for k, v in row.items() if k != 'name'])
```

Switch to a generator rather than a list comprehension

```
all(str_count(k)==int(v) for k, v in row.items() if k != 'name')
```

Comment: Im afraid I don't quite follow,

Comment: @Kwsswart--one question first.  Where is str_count coming from?  Only reference if find is [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/blob/master/R/count.r) which is R not Python.  I just assume it's available for your code.

Comment: Hey Darryl thanks your answer seems to work I am just trying to understand exactly why it works. and str_count is from an earlier part of the program where I have already iterated through a text to count the patterns inside of the text and calculate how many consecutive appearances of the STR or 'AGATC', etc.

Comment: str_count is a self made dictionary that I have used in order to keep tract of the counts while iterating through the sequence

Comment: @Kwsswart--added more explanation. Does this help?

Comment: Alot thank you so much @DarryIG going to bookmark to keep as a reference while I continue to learn Python